# Adding data to database using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add data to the Event table in SQL Server.
This is the table details:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event]
(
    [EventID] [int] IDENTITY(1001,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EventDesc] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EventLogo] [image] NULL,
    [EventLocation] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
    [EventDate] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [EventStartTime] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [EventEndTime] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [NumOfAttendees] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
    [EventStatus] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NULL,
    [RatingID] [int] NULL,
    [FeedbackID] [int] NULL
)
```

This is where I receive the error:

> Keyword, identifier or string expected after verbatim specifier @

This is the `EventController` code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var events = db.Events.Include(@ => @.Category).Include(@ => @.Feedback).Include(@ => @.Rating).Include(@ => @.User);
    return View(events.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Keyword, identifier or string expected after verbatim specifier @ in the index action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to -

```
db.Events.Include(c => c.Category).Include(f => f.Feedback).Include(r => r.Rating).Include(u => u.User);
```

@ is a keyword which is used for verbatim literals.

Comment: @JohnaneUmslana if this answer solves your issue, then consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/255183) this answer so other people will know that your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up ekad